# Is there a way to do a J-Cut or L-Cut in the video editor?

Tags: edit-mode, video-sequence-editor, video

I'm in the process of trimming down a video in Blender and I was wondering if there was a way make an L-Cut or a J-Cut. Is it possible?

Comment: The audio and video strips are independent, so I don't see why not

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's just a matter of cutting (<kbd>K</kbd>) between the video and audio strips at separate frames. For example, here's an L cut:

[image: L-cut in vse]